# How many ways there are to declare variables in facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I noticed that c:set does not work well used inside "include of include of include", as important notice facelets documentation does't recommend it too.

Now I am using ui:param inside ui:include, but it is a bit dispersive when no attached notes about params comes with the include, is there something other way to declare "global vars"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a matter of trying to fit old JSP programming into the JSF framework. You should be using backing beans to hold your data.

If you try to hard-code data directly into your xhtml file, you are defeating the purpose of JSF's MVC framework. If you have a specific example of what you are trying to do, I could give you a specific recommendation.

Comment: I need for skinning purpose, like many CSS colors variables inside a page, a backing bean for this purpose could be too much expensive?

Comment: no, it's fine. Actually, RichFaces uses a backing bean for just such a purpose.